# How to store text of all web elements and then print the text of all the elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, arraylist

```
 List<WebElement> GroupList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[Abc']"));
      
   for (WebElement element: GroupList){
            logger.info(element.getText());
     }
```

Current Code is just printing the text of all elements one by one. I want to store the texts in a single List and then print that list, Further i want to print text in this way "Abc, def, ghi" every element has comma and space between them and the last element would just print the element text and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> textList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<WebElement> GroupList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//ABC)"));

        for ( WebElement element: GroupList) {
            {
                textList.add(element.getText());
            }
        }
        logger.info(textList);
        logger.info(String.join(", ", textList));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
List<String> textList = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] xpathStrings = {"//*[Abc']", "//*[def']", "//*[ghi']"};
for (String xpathString: xpathStrings) {
   List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathString));
   for (WebElement element: elements) {
      textList.add(element.getText().replace("'", ""));
   }
}
logger.info(textList);
logger.info(String.join(", ", textList));
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help my scenario was a little different although but you solved the problem. I had to first gettext of all the elements that are not hard coded. i just gave the abc, def, ghi for example. then i had to store all the elements in a List string then print it. By editing your code the problem was solved. please see my answer below to the question i asked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> singleList = new ArrayList<String>();

List<WebElement> GroupList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[Abc']"));

for (WebElement element : GroupList) {
    singleList.add(element.getText());
}

for (int i = 0; i < singleList.size() - 1; i++) {

    system.out.print(singleList.get(i) + " ,");
}

system.out.print(singleList.get(singleList.size() - 1));
```

Comment: The code example in your answer is poorly formatted. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks for guidance.